# Unity list item is leaving extra space in high resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a vertical Scroll List. I have developed this app for resolution 768*1024. In this resolution my List is working fine. But when I run my app in higher resolution(1440*2960) it leave some space around all 4 direction.

[image: List view on higher resolution]

[image: content Size filter and vertical Layout Group]

[image: List Item size]

[image: Canvas Scaler]

I have also tried with changing Layout element min height dynamically, but Spacing issue is still exist.

Comment: You mean the spacing between those white boxes? Also could you share a screenshot of how your Canvas is setup? particularly Canvas Scalar component?

Comment: I have updated my question and added Canvas scalar part

Answer (score 1):

Vertical and horizontal layout set element position in (screen width/height divided by a number of elements) * element number, in other words, they space out all elements evenly across canvas space. To achieve what you want you either have to enable **child control size -> height** option or write a script that aligns your elements in the center of the screen and one after another taking in consideration their height.